# Media query: how to make text change color when window width gets below 600px

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I want to make my text change color when the window size gets below 600px:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LgsXT/1/

text:

```
<div class = "derp">derp derp derp</div>
```

css:

```
.derp {
color:red;
}

@media (max-width:600) {
    .derp {
        color:blue;
    }
}
```

But it's not doing anything. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a px or other unit for the @media rule.
Also, watch those spaces in your HTML, and I would suggest you work up instead of down in screen-size

```
<div class="my-box">Derp</div>


.my-box {
    color: red;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {

    .my-box {
        color:blue;
    }

} /* end break point */
```

Here is a more robust [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/LhZeN/)

Comment: thank you, working up does make sense! mobile first :]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a unit to your value in the query otherwise the number has no meaning so it would look like this:

```
.derp {
    color:red;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
    .derp {
        color:blue;
    }
}
```