# How to add css rule for when div reaches window width

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have an image with text vertically alligned next to it that drops down when the window size is too small, and continues wrapping for each word as the window shrinks.

https://jsfiddle.net/sj0sLevf/3/

```css
#header-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0;
}

#header-txt {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: initial;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
}

.h1-header-txt {
  margin: 0 0 0;
}

#header-img {
  display: inline-block;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-wrapper">
  <div id="header-img"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2215/1909/files/icon-alivehm_4fbccdb6-8ec5-4aaa-b6af-e6915d2c0315_large.png" /></div>
  <div id="header-txt">
    <h1 class="h1-header-txt">HEADER THAT CHANGES SIZE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have been trying to make it so that when the text first drops down, it triggers some more perameters in the css that get applied to `.h1-header-txt`so I can modify the colour, margins ect. Now, I have looked around and media queries such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442274/media-query-how-to-make-text-change-color-when-window-width-gets-below-600px) work fine on my code, however they dont quite solve my problem as the pixel width at which I want the query to trigger is different depending on the size of the header.

Media Queries can still probably solve my problem, and I may be missing something obvious but I just can't find the right argument to check if my header has reached the edge of the window.

If there is a helpful condition I can parse into `@media`, or another way to accomplish this that I am not seeing, any input would be appreciated.

Comment: *How to add css element* CSS doesn't have elements. CSS has rules. The DOM has elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Javascript(jQuery) to monitor the screen width. What I did was  **total up the width or your icon and header and compare with the screen width**. Once the width is smaller than the total width add `.active` class where the font size can be controlled.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    minitorScreen();
  });

  minitorScreen();

  function minitorScreen() {
    var $headerWidth = $(".h1-header-txt").innerWidth();
    var $screenWidth = $(document).innerWidth();
    var $iconWidth = $("#header-img").innerWidth();

    var $hstotalWidth = $iconWidth + $headerWidth

    console.log("icon + header = "+ $hstotalWidth );
    console.log("screen = "+ $screenWidth);

    if ($iconWidth + $headerWidth + 20 >= $screenWidth) { //additional 20px for precautionary measures
      alert("you have reached the width limit");

      $(".h1-header-txt").addClass("active");
    } else {
      $(".h1-header-txt").removeClass("active");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#header-wrapper {
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 0;
}
#header-txt {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: initial;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
}
.h1-header-txt {
  margin: 0 0 0;
}
#header-img {
  display: inline-block;
  *zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.active {
  zoom: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header-wrapper">
  <div id="header-img"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2215/1909/files/icon-alivehm_4fbccdb6-8ec5-4aaa-b6af-e6915d2c0315_large.png" /></div>
  <div id="header-txt">
    <h1 class="h1-header-txt">HEADER THAT CHANGES SIZE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have approved since this works! thankyou! but i am still interested if someone has a simpler way

Comment: I don't think it is possible as you mentioned earlier that your header will be dynamic which mean it can be long or short. CSS media query is good for building responsive layout but it wasn't able to monitor dynamic content.